Preferences datastore not giving correct value for Android widget with Jetpack glance?
I have created an android project, I am using Jetpack glance to create android widget, I need to display the value which is stored in Preferences datastore in my android widget, I am able to update the value of Preferences datastore from my android app and the value is persisted even after app reloads, I then created an android widget from my app and it says There are multiple DataStores active for the same file: /data/user/0/com.codingwithnobody.myandroidproject/files/datastore/user_preferences.preferences_pb. You should either maintain your DataStore as a singleton or confirm that there is no two DataStore's active on the same file (by confirming that the scope is cancelled).
Here is my code
private const val USER_PREFERENCES = "user_preferences"


@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DataStoreModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDataStore(@ApplicationContext context: Context): DataStore<Preferences> {
        return PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create (
            produceFile = { context.preferencesDataStoreFile(USER_PREFERENCES) }
        )
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDataStoreRepository(dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>): DataStoreRepository {
        return DataStoreRepository(dataStore)
    }
}

@Singleton
class DataStoreRepository @Inject constructor(private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>) {

    private object PreferencesKeys {
        val COUNTER_KEY = intPreferencesKey("counter_key")
    }

    // Get the current counter value as a Flow
    val counterFlow: Flow<Int> = dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.COUNTER_KEY] ?: 0 // Default to 0 if no value is stored
        }

    // Increment the counter value
    suspend fun incrementCounter() {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            val currentValue = preferences[PreferencesKeys.COUNTER_KEY] ?: 0
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.COUNTER_KEY] = currentValue + 1
        }
    }
}


class MyWidget: GlanceAppWidget() {

    override val sizeMode = SizeMode.Exact

    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {

        provideContent {

            GlanceTheme {
                val dataStore = PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create {
                    context.preferencesDataStoreFile("user_preferences")
                }
                val size = LocalSize.current
                val dataStoreRepository = remember { DataStoreRepository(dataStore) }
                val counter by dataStoreRepository.counterFlow.collectAsState(initial = 0)
                
                Scaffold(
                    titleBar = {
                        TitleBar(startIcon = ImageProvider(R.mipmap.ic_launcher), title = "Hello")
                    }, backgroundColor = GlanceTheme.colors.widgetBackground
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = GlanceModifier.background(color = Color.Red)
                            .padding(30.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Counter value is ${counter}",
                            style = TextStyle(
                                color = ColorProvider(
                                    color = Color(0xFF000000)
                                ),
                                fontSize = 12.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            ),
                            modifier = GlanceModifier.clickable {
                                actionStartActivity(activity = MainActivity::class.java)
                            }
                        )

                        Button("Start Activity", onClick = actionStartActivity<MainActivity>(), style = TextStyle(
                            color = ColorProvider(
                                color = Color(0x00FF0000)
                            ),
                            fontSize = 12.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                        ),)
                    }
                }



            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCompositionError(
        context: Context,
        glanceId: GlanceId,
        appWidgetId: Int,
        throwable: Throwable
    ) {
        super.onCompositionError(context, glanceId, appWidgetId, throwable)
        val remoteView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.custom_error_layout)
        Log.i("errorMessageis","${throwable.message} ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textview,"${throwable.message} ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView)
    }


}

How to use this with Dagger Hilt in an Android widget?
I have tried looking into GlanceStateDefinition as well but the problem with GlanceStateDefinition is I can't really update GlanceStateDefinition until the user has already created the widget and for the first time the GlanceStateDefinition data will be empty. In my app , if I had a button and on click of it , I call the below code
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                val glanceIds =
                    GlanceAppWidgetManager(this@MainActivity).getGlanceIds(MyWidget::class.java)
                glanceIds.forEach { id ->
                    updateAppWidgetState(this@MainActivity, id) {
                        it[longPreferencesKey("now")] = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    }
                    MyWidget().update(this@MainActivity, id)
                }
            }

but this will never be called if the user has never created the widget and once the user creates the widget he will see empty value for the first time until I press the button in my app again.
